# JavaScript code to evaluate string arithmetic expression containing multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to pass an arithmetic expression as a string to Javascript and this string can contain any number of numerical arrays which will be dynamically populated.

For Eg: I need to evaluate the below expression

```
(pmPdcpVolDlDrb+pmPdcpVolDlSrb)/8/1024 , Where both pmPdcpVolDlDrb and pmPdcpVolDlSrb are numeric arrays

pmPdcpVolDlDrb =[ Array containing values for sensor pmPdcpVolDlDrb read from storage]
pmPdcpVolDlDrb =[ Array containing values for sensor pmPdcpVolDlDrb read from storage]
```

This expression can change and the number of variables involved can also change. I need a generalized way of handling it. I wrote the below code and it serves my purpose. I need to know if there is a better and standard way for the same.

```
// Expression for evaluation where pmPdcpVolDlDrb and pmPdcpVolDlSrb are arrays
expression="(pmPdcpVolDlDrb+pmPdcpVolDlSrb)/8/1024"
// Seperating out the variables from the expression. In my case variable names always start with pm
variables=expression.split(/\W+/).filter(word => word.includes("pm"));
array=[]
for(i=0;i<variables.length;i++){
    array[i]= [1,2,3,4]// Replace with actual code to get the values of arrays to be computed
    if (i===0)
        expression=expression.replace(variables[i],"a")
    else
    expression=expression.replace(variables[i],"array["+i+"][i]")
}
resultantArray=array[0].map((a, i) => eval(expression))
```